# junit test for EJB

Tags: jakarta-ee, junit, jboss, ejb, mbeans

I am planning for junit test cases for some of my EJBs. I did little bit of Google and most of the links points to arquillian http://arquillian.org but it seems that arquillian is slow and it requires a running container. Can i use arquillian  to test jboss service bean (org.jboss.ejb3.annotation.Service) - an example would be a great help?

A little bit of investigation lead me to *JBoss Microcontainer* http://docs.jboss.org/jbossmc/docs/2.0.x/userGuide/index.html. Does this Microcontainer need any running instance of jboss? Can I deploy all types of EJBs + jboss service bean in this microcontainer?

Further, what is the difference between *jboss microcontainer* vs *JBossEmbeddedAS* https://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossEmbeddedASQuickstartAndRunnableExample

Thanks in advance

Dipankaj

Comment: You may want to look into openEJB as well.  Very easy to set up and super fast startup within Eclipse. It autodetects EJB and MDB in your project and binds it to JNDI.

Answer (score 3):

The purpose of a unit test is to test only a single unit of code, e.g. your bean class.

So, your unit test should not require any infrastructure and should mock out all necessary references to other units.

I know that in real life this is often hard to achieve, but nevertheless if you want to have any container services, e.g. injection mechanisms, then your test is beyond a unit test.

Arquillian provides container adaptors, so that your test case can run in an embedded or even in a real container. One of its benefits is the ability to run the test in a real application server instead of some simulated environment and to run the same test in several environments, e.g. on different application servers.

So in your case I would recommend to write unit cases for everything which is unit testable (you will see that if you do the test in parallel to developing the unit, you'll take care to make it well testable) and use a mocking framework (e.g. Mockito) for every external reference and then use Arquillian for those cases where you have integration tests.

Comment: thanks Geziefer... can you please little focus on Microcontainer also... can I assume it as a "mini jboss" which can be start/stop/deploy using java code?

Comment: @dipankaj I have not used the Microcontainer, but as the reference you provided states, it's the "JBoss's JMX Microkernel to support direct POJO deployment and standalone use outside the JBoss application server." - so it's not an EJB container. JBoss Embedded AS provides "end-user API for the creation, configuration, lifecycle, and deployment operations of the JBoss Application Server." - so you can bootstrap an AS in your test case. We used this in Seam 2 projects in combination with TestNG. - But still, I'd recommend to do integration tests as close to the real container as possible.

Answer (score 2):

We use **[EJB3Unit](http://ejb3unit.sourceforge.net/)** with very good results. It doesn't require a container at all. It injects **@DataSource, @PersistenceContext, @Resource and @EJB**.

It also has limitations, as it is not a container, like it doesn't create transactions and doesn't run interceptors. But you will test @Interceptor and @Transaction with an integration test don't you?

Answer (score 2):

I've recently made public my homegrown container-less EJB unit-testing farmework, see examples in [testfun-JEE](https://github.com/michaelyaakoby/testfun).

testfun-JEE supports injections of EJBs and [Mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/) mocks as well as using JPA and JDBC.